# Set cookies to text value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to add cookies to a function. In this example, I want the browser to remember the value of p, which is "Number One" after the input button `#sting` is clicked. When the page is refreshed I would like the empty p tag to already have the text "Number One."

The HTML

```
<p id="place"></p>
<input id="sting" type="submit" value="Run"/>
```

The JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#sting', function(){
$('#place').text("Number One");
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xwgj4w67/

I have looked into the jQuery cookie plugin(https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v1.5.1), but am unsure of how to use it. I would be happy with examples either with or without the plugin. Thanks.

Comment: why would you use cookies? This can be handled by your server side language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage to store any values into browser:

To set value in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('place', "Number One");
```

To get value from local storage:

```
localStorage.getItem('place');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies in Javascript. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

To set a cookie,

```
 document.cookie = 'Number=1';
```

To get a cookie,

```
var x = document.cookie;
```